# How to deal with the elements in the array in the following format?

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array:
    $a = [1,2,3,4,5];
Processed format：

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
2,3
2,4
2,5
3,4
3,5
4,5
```

The two elements are a group. If only the last element is left, it ends.

Comment: what's your question ..  .. explain better  .

Comment: Can you please add your question?

Comment: the result seems like an associative array but your code is not. The question seems unclear. What is your goal?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post accordingly in order for us to better understand what your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];

foreach($a as $key => $value)
{
    for($i = $key + 1; $i < count($a); $i++)
    {
        echo $value.",".$a[$i]."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can echo as many parameters as you like and do not need to concatenate. Use comma instead of dot.

Comment: I also think of this. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: your code assumes that all indices in `$a` are numeric. The code would fail - or at least not work as expected - if there is an alphanumeric indice. I would suggest to add `$a = array_values($a);` before foreach in order to ensure that the code works.